# ReactJS & i18n.js: Translations with links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization, i18n-js

I have a ReactJS project that's using i18n.js for translations.

In i18n JSON file I have a line like this:

```
"register": {
    "terms": "I have read and accept the Terms of Service"
}
```

I want only the "Terms of Service" part of the sentence to be a link.

At first I tried something like this:

```
<label className="lead">
    {i18n.t('register.terms').substr(0, 27)}<a href="#">{i18n.t('register.terms').substr(27, 43)}</a>
</label>
```

But well, of course it does not work with any other language than english.

Is there a way to do this **without splitting the string value** in two fields in the JSON file?

Comment: Does it related to React? is it works with react (& english)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

You can create an array.

```
"terms": ["I have read and accept the ", "Terms of Service"]
```

And then get the values like that:

```
<p>{i18n.t('terms.0')}<a href="#">{i18n.t('terms.1')}</a></p>
```

Comment: This might cause some issues with non-English locales where the ordering of words is different